# How to Hide Calendar/Activity Details by user wise?

Tags: event, activities, calendar, sharing-rule, owd

I have imported A,B,C,D User Event details in Admin User. those all user events are Showing in admin calendar view. like below Image. How can i see particular users details in separate tab like calendar tab, below like A User Calendar, B user Calendar...etc.

[image]

when i am login in "A" user, in calendar view all users events details are showing. How can i hide another users events details in "A" user calendar

Answer (score 1):

It basically depends on the owner. Activities are by default `Private` in the `Org-Wide-Defaults`, so if you have no sharing rules created or Apex Sharing logic, it would be as easy as assigning the correct owners to each of the activities.